# Highcharts polar chart not connecting lines properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am having a very weird issue when using the polar options in `highcharts-more`. This is what it looks like...
[image]

Below is my full code (it is wrapped in a React component)

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Card, CardHeader, CardText, CircularProgress } from 'material-ui'
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts'
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts-more'
import colors from '../../../colors'

HighchartsMore(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts)

const styles = {
  textAlignLeft: {
    textAlign: 'left'
  },
  loadingCardText: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
}

const View = ({data1, data2, data3, data4, loading, hasEtfBeenSelected, highchartsAreaThreshold}) => {
  if (!hasEtfBeenSelected) {
    return (<div />)
  }

  let config = {
    credits: false,
    chart: {
      polar: true,
      type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    pane: {
      size: '80%',
      startAngle: 22.5
    },
    colors: [
      colors.color1, colors.color2, colors.color3, colors.color4
    ],
    xAxis: {
      categories: data1.map(x => x[0]),
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
      lineWidth: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        threshold: highchartsAreaThreshold
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
      lineWidth: 0,
      min: highchartsAreaThreshold,
      startOnTick: false,
      tickAmount: 5
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      valuePrefix: '$'
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 70,
      layout: 'vertical'
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Data1',
        data: data1,
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        },
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        lineWidth: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Data2',
        data: data2,
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        },
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        lineWidth: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Data3',
        data: data3,
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        },
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        lineWidth: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Data4',
        data: data4,
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        },
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        lineWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  }

  if (loading) {
    return (<div>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader title='Spreads' style={styles.textAlignLeft} />
        <CardText style={styles.loadingCardText}>
          <CircularProgress size={70} thickness={5} />
        </CardText>
      </Card>
    </div>)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader title='Spreads'
          style={styles.textAlignLeft} />
        <CardText>
          <ReactHighcharts config={config} />
        </CardText>
      </Card>
    </div>
  )
}

View.propTypes = {
  data1: PropTypes.array,
  data2: PropTypes.array,
  data3: PropTypes.array,
  data4: PropTypes.array,
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
  hasEtfBeenSelected: PropTypes.bool,
  highchartsAreaThreshold: PropTypes.number
}

export default View
```

`highchartsAreaThreshold` is set to be the minimum of all the data (so that the chart colors negative data). This is weird because this exact code actually worked yesterday. So it's random. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: Here is some sample data (data1..data4 all look like this):

```
data1:
Array[8]
0: 0.01
1: 0
2: -0.007
3: 0.014
4: -0.001
5: 0.021
6: 0
7: 0.01

data2:
Array[8]
0: 0.04
1: 0.02
2: 0.003
3: 0.031
4: -0.03
5: -0.006
6: -0.03
7: 0.04
```

I just tried using a simple array instead of an array of 2d vectors as suggested but I get the same result.

Comment: What does your data look like?  Is It sorted?

Comment: Nope. Does it have to be?

Comment: I noticed a similar behavior if the data was not sorted in a line chart

Comment: Yes, the data needs to be sorted.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird the data in this example is not sorted. https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider

Comment: Can you include the data and all the necessary variables? Your issue is not reproducible right now.

Comment: are you passing cartesian data ( eg 2d vectors ) ? if yes, doc says 2d coordinates will be converted to polar, are you setting the angle correctly and orderly ? ( the polar-spider example passes a simple 1d array as data, hence no sorting is necessary )...

Comment: Added some data @morganfree. I was indeed passing 2d data but I just tried 1d and no good. Maybe it has to do with my rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after investigating, I've realized that it has nothing to do with the official highcharts library... it actually has to do with the `react-highcharts` library. The offending line is the following:

`HighchartsMore(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts)`

Apparently you're only supposed to do this once globally but I was doing it twice, one for each spider chart. This was causing this weird behavior because I'm guessing it was removing the `highcharts-more` functionality by applying `HighchartsMore()` twice. The solution is to only run that line once in a top level react component like in `App.js` or something high. Then there will be no issues.

Thank you everyone for your help. My original code is actually correct.

Answer (score 2):

Please, check your `highchartsAreaThreshold`, I think this the problem, compare examples:

- threshold = 0.00: http://jsfiddle.net/q9th3btr/ (wrong, similar to your sample)
- threshold = -0.05: http://jsfiddle.net/q9th3btr/1/ (fine)

Most probably this part of code is exactly the same, but something changed how `highchartsAreaThreshold` is calculated and has wrong value.

Comment: I had this same issue and this did the trick - nice catch and thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't have the environment on me right now to test but I want to award you for helping me. I'm certain something like this will fix it. I'll accept your answer on Tuesday when I get to try it out again.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't show the data so I'd guess that the culprit is bad 2d data.

According to highcharts doc, the polar chart works both with 1d and 2d data:

If you pass a 1d vector angles will be calculated automatically and incrementally ( eg. `[1,2,3]` -> `[[0,1],[a,2],[2a,3]]` ) where a is the                 pointInterval, so no line crossing can occur in this case.(*)

But, if you pass a 2d vector the first coordinate will be used to interpolate the angle ( eg something like `[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]]` -> `[[0,1],[2pi*a/(a+b+c),2],...]` ); so, if angles are not properly sorted you may end up with crossing lines ( for example, `[[0,2],[2,2],[4,2],[1,3]]` ).

EDIT: 1d data can also cross with negative values; apparently, setting yAxis min/max and threshold seems not fixing the issue as it should be ... a solution may be to set yAxis:min and thresold to 0 and rescale the data manually in this case

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it didn't work. I was passing 2D data before and just changed to 1d as added in the question.

Comment: @coolboyjules what happens if you remove ( or flip ) the negative values ?